# Errno 13 - while iterating an csv.writer

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I can't figure out why I am having a "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '..\Output'"

Here is part of the code:

```
with open (o,'a+') as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out, lineterminator= '\n')    
    for items in Data:    
        wr.writerow(items)
        out.close
```

Actually this is a part of a module that i have created.

Instead this is the iterator that calls the module:

```
for tabs in range(len(cDirs)):
    Rwdif(cDirs[tabs],outDir)
```

The point is that i have Errno 13 only with the last file of the iterator.

Can someone help me? 
THX

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path you are writing to isnt open in excel or any other program and report back :)